# Does Mathematica have an order relationship for lists, or a general ordering relation?

Tags: sorting, order

`{1, 2} < {3, 4}` doesn't seem to work, but `Sort[{{3, 4}, {1, 2}}]` yields `{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}`.

I want to use the order relationship that `Sort` uses for my program

(lexicographic ordering will do fine, doesn't really matter what I use so long as it's a strict total order)

I'm used to Haskell automagically deriving such an order for any data types I construct, via the Ord class.

Edit: The `Order` function does what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way might be to use [Ordering](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ordering.html)

```
list = {{3, 4}, {1, 2}};
ord = Ordering[list]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
list[[ord]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I've looked it up from your functions. It appears what I'm looking for is the `Order` function.