# Does default 'Sort' generate always the same result?

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

Does default 'Sort' output always the same result regardless if we  change its order?

Suppose that

```
L = {E1,E2,E3,E4,E5}
```

(*here E1,..,E5 means any possible mathematica expressions)

Is it true that `Sort[{E1,E2,E3,E4,E5}]` and `Sort[{E4,E1,E3,E5,E2}]` will generate the same result ?

Note that the answer is generally 'no', if we use non-default sort.
For example,
`Sort[{1,x,2},Greater]` gives `{1,x,2}` while
`Sort[{2,x,1},Greater]` gives `{2,x,1}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort takes as second argument an ordering function that is expected to either return `True`/ `False` , or to return `0` `1` , `-1` . With `0` corresponding to equality between the two arguments. The problem with using `Greater` as an ordering function is that it does not always do that. `Greater[1 , 2]`  evaluates to `False`, which is good, but `Greater[2 , x]` evaluates to itself. Which is neither `True` / `False` nor `0` , `1` ,`-1`.

So `Greater` is not a proper ordering function when applied to non-numbers.  The default ordering function used by Sort is  `Order` :
`Order[2, x]` evaluates to `1`, indicating that, as an expression, `x` is "greater" that `2` in Mathematica's canonical ordering. Unlike `Greater`, `Order` always works as an ordering function, returning `1` , `0` or `-1` for any pair of expressions.

The result of Sort should be unambiguous as long as your ordering function is strict and properly-defined for all the elements in your list.

[Related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/219647/does-mathematica-have-an-order-relationship-for-lists-or-a-general-ordering-rel)

Comment: So the conclusion is Yes! : Sort[{E1,E2,E3,E4,E5}] and Sort[{E4,E1,E3,E5,E2}] will generate the same result, regardless of what E1,E2,E3,E4,E5 are. Here E1,..,E5 means any possible mathematica expressions.